# Data structure for NumPy indexed array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 2D NumPy array `(N, D)` where each row has a unique index (a non-negative integer). The indices of the rows are increasing. For example, the indices of my `(4,D)` array could be `(10, 20, 21, 30)`.

I'm looking for a data structure that allows me to:

- Select rows from their indices: `arr[21]` instead of `arr[2]` (i.e. absolute rather than relative indexing)
- Convert an arbitrary list of absolute indices to relative indices, and conversely. For example, convert back and forth between `[10, 30, 21, 21]` and `[0, 3, 2, 2]`.

What is the cleanest way to implement this?

1. Creating a brand new class, wrapping the data (the NumPy array) and the index. Implementing `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, etc.
2. Creating a class deriving from `ndarray` and overriding indexing such that the absolute indices are used.
3. Keeping separate objects for the data and the index (both as NumPy arrays), implementing functions like `select(data, index)`, and using that everywhere in the code.
4. Like (3), but the index is an instance of a custom class, providing methods such as `index.to_relative(data)` and `index.to_absolute(data)`
5. Using masked arrays.

I'm sure one can find yet other approaches. I can find pros and cons for all of these approaches. What would be the cleanest way to do it? Is there a "standard" way of doing it that I would be unaware of?

Comment: I don't understand this question. When you say `(N, D)`, do you mean you have an N-dimensional array? And, when you say the indices could be `(10, 20, 21, 30)`, do you mean that is the shape of your array? Could you provide examples of what you're trying to do, and how it doesn't work?

Comment: 3. using a function will be the simplest.  But if you prefer the indexing notation (`[]`) versus argument notation, `np.lib.index_tricks` has examples of classes that implement custom `__getitem__` functions.

Comment: @farenorth I have clarified the question. My array is 2-dimensional, the shape is `(N, D)`. `(10, 20, 21, 30)` are just arbitrary integers associated to the rows (in this case, there are four rows, so N=4). I know how to implement all 5 approaches, but I'm not sure which one is the cleanest.

Comment: @CyrilleRossant I understand now. Have you considered this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html

Comment: Also, it seems to me that you are asking two questions: 1) what is the 'cleanest' way to implement a method for doing this in userspace, which seems to be a question of style, and 2) what is the fastest/most-efficient method for large arrays. The fastest method may prescribe a subset of implementations, but if you're really looking for the most-efficient method you should ask for that. I'm no expert on speed, but if I were you I'd try running some speed tests on: scipy.sparse.csr_matrix, dict lookup, list lookup (@asimoneau's solution). Then choose an implementation that seems appropriate.

Comment: My arrays are not sparse. Also, the question of style is indeed different from the question of the implementation. I know how to implement that relatively efficiently with NumPy, and the same implementation would be used identically with all those approaches. So my question was really about style. I guess there's no standard way of doing it so I'll just have to choose!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard way to do this, but is not overly complicated to implement.

For (3), if you use a list of index instead of an array, you can use the `index` method to get the index of a value :

```
i = [10,20,21,30]
x = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
x[i.index(20)] # -> array([4,5,6])
```

Of course you can't assign using this and modifying the structure could be a pain.

Depending on the complexity of the program, I would use this directly or create a class that encapsulate this, as you suggested. I think both method can be qualified as "clean" since the first one doesn't require any other functions or class definitions and the second makes the utilization very easy and intuitive.

Comment: I forgot to say: my arrays are quite big (N can have 100 million elements, D may be between 1 and 1000), and I may need to convert millions of indices between relative and absolute coordinates. I'm not sure how `list.index` will scale to these volumes.